# Remove a specific node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nodes

I'm working on an application which has to open a **.xmcd** file which has xml file format, so I need delete a specific tag.

My problem is: when i tried open the file with "XDocument" gives a format error.

How can i delete this node:

```
<ml:provenance expr-id="1" xmlns:ml="http://schemas.mathsoft.com/math30">

    <originRef doc-id="F4B30933-A622-46E8-A8A6-77A7B48C1717" 
    version-id="0016E28D-557A-4590-AA4E-FA137EAFF367"
    branch-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" revision-num="3372908" 
    is-modified="false" region-id="0"
    href="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mathcad\Mathcad 14\qsheet\symbols.xmcd"         
    xmlns="http://schemas.mathsoft.com/provenance10">


</ml:provenance>
```

Comment: What error?  Is that the complete XML?  It isn't valid because the `originRef` tag isn't closed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to close the tag. The problem is that no xml extension and throws the error when trying to open it as such. Is there a way to open it and delete it without XDocument?